# Tweet Bot/Twitter Account for Retrocomputing?

Tags: discussion, status-planned, site-promotion, twitter

Some Stack Exchange network sites have a twitter account which tweet recent or hot questions, as see on the [site list](http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic):

[image: Sites with Twitter Accounts]

The timeline on the post then shows that the question was tweeted by that site's specific account:

[image: Timeline]

How can we add a Twitter account to tweet recent Retrocomputing questions?  Does this account need to be run by the mods or Stack Exchange employees?

Comment: Twitter accounts are owned by the SE network itself - http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106022/236563 .  I'll ask the question.

Comment: It'll have to be the mods on this one; like with the blog, Stack Exchange won't give us a Twitter bot because they don't do them any more. @Chenmunka, can you handle this one?

Comment: @Chenmunka I'll see if I can write us a basic bot. https://github.com/wizzwizz4/retrostack-birdsong